# AWS Lambda stack definition YAML

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml

## Design

My desired outcome is as follows:

1. S3 event triggers Lambda Function `startTextractStateMachine`
2. Lambda Function `startTextractStateMachine` kicks off State Machine `textractStepFunc` execution (AWS Step Functions)
3. State Machine `textractStepFunc` starts with Lambda Function `callTextract`; calls Textract async command to start process
4. Output of Textract command is attached to SQS queue `TextractSQS`
5. SQS queue output triggers Lambda Function `getTextractOutput`
6. Lambda Function `getTextractOutput` publishes message to SNS Topic
7. SNS Topic triggers final Lambda Function `parseTextractOutput` via subscription
8. Done

## Implementation

I made this system work *without* any AWS Step Functions initially, but realized that I needed more control over retry/failure of the individual Lambda Functions (especially `callTextract`), so I've tried to move the system to AWS Step Functions *and* the Serverless Framework at the same time.

I've come to realize it was harder than I thought it would be. I keep running into roadblocks with the Serverless Framework.

I used several guides, blog posts and Github issues ([here](https://serverless.com/blog/how-to-manage-your-aws-step-functions-with-serverless/), [here](https://medium.com/@mebnoah/aws-step-functions-serverless-framework-752cce8f29fd) and [here](https://github.com/DavidWells/serverless-workshop/blob/master/lessons-code-complete/events/step-functions/serverless.yml)) to reach this point, but am permanently stuck.

### Serverless Setup

I've left out much of my Design ideas and simply need to have the S3 event trigger when a file is added to the Bucket.

Here is my configuration file:

```
# serverless.yml

service: textract-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7
  timeout: 10
  region: us-east-1
  environment:
    STATE_MACHINE_ARN: ${self:resources.Outputs.TextractStepFunctions.Value}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "s3:PutObject"
        - "states:*"
      Resource:
        Fn::Join:
          - ""
          - - "<the-chumiest-bucket's ARN> or *"
            - ${self:resources.Outputs.TextractStepFunctions.Value}

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-existing-s3
  - serverless-step-functions
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters

layers:
  boto3Layer:
    package:
      artifact: boto3_layer.zip
    allowedAccounts:
      - "*"

functions:
  startTextractStateMachine:
    handler: src/start_textract_state_machine.lambda_handler
    role: arn:...lambda-s3-role
    layers:
      - {Ref: Boto3LayerLambdaLayer}
    events:
      - existingS3:
          bucket: the-chumiest-bucket
          events:
            - s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: input1/
            - suffix: .pdf
      - existingS3:
          bucket: the-chumiest-bucket
          events:
            - s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: input2/
            - suffix: .pdf
  callTextract:
    handler: src/call_textract.lambda_handler
    role: arn:...lambda-s3-role
    layers:
      - {Ref: Boto3LayerLambdaLayer}
  getTextractOutput:
    handler: src/get_textract_output.lambda_handler
    role: arn:...lambda-s3-role
    layers:
      - {Ref: Boto3LayerLambdaLayer}
  parseTextractOutput:
    handler: src/parse_textract_output.lambda_handler
    role: arn:...lambda-s3-role
    layers:
      - {Ref: Boto3LayerLambdaLayer}

stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    textractStepFunc:
      name: TextractStepFunctions
      definition:
        StartAt: StartTextractStateMachine
        States:
          StartTextractStateMachine:
            Type: Task
            Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:function:#{AWS::StackName}-startTextractStateMachine"
            Next: CallTextract
          CallTextract:
            Type: Task
            Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:function:#{AWS::StackName}-callTextract"
            End: true

resources:
  Outputs:
    TextractStepFunctions:
      Description: The ARN of the state machine
      Value:
        Ref: TextractStepFunctions
```

How I deploy it:

```
sls deploy -v && sls s3deploy
```